# Plugin and base class constructor

Tags: c++, qt

In a Qt application I declare a base class:

```
class Base:
  public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();
    virtual void doSomething();
};
```

Both the c-tor/d-tor and `doSomething()` have default implementations in a separate source file.
Furthermore, I provide an abstract interface to implement Qt's plugin scheme, like in the [Echo Plugin Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-echoplugin-example.html).

```
class Interface {
  public:
    virtual ~Interface() {}
    virtual Base *create() = 0;
};

#define Interface_iid "blag"
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(Interface, Interface_iid)
```

In a plugin that resides in a shared library, `libPlugin.so` I derive from this base class to provide custom implementations:

```
class Special:
  public Base {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Special() { /* Implementation */ }
    void doSomething() { /* Implementation */ }
};
```

Finally I also implement the plugin interface:

```
class Q_DECL_EXPORT Plugin:
  public QObject,
  public Interface {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID Interface_iid)
    Q_INTERFACES(Interface)

  public:
    Base *create() {
      return new Special();
    }
};
```

Now I can load this plugin via `QPluginLoader` and obtain access to its core object, which correctly identifies itself being a `Plugin`. But when I try to `ThePlugin::create()` the `Special` object, I get a linkage error:

```
symbol lookup error: libPlugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4BaseC2Ev
```

Beneath the name mangling, I suppose this refers to the `Base::Base` c-tor that is needed when constructing the derived `Special` object.

I'm tempted to compare to, e.g. a `QStylePlugin`: It basically does the same, returning some `QStyle`-derived class via an abstract interface. Please refer to the [Style Plugin Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-styleplugin-example.html). Yet I guess the difference is that in the case of the style plugin, both the application (that provides the custom style plugin) and the style plugin itself are linked against the common Qt library that provides, e.g. the c-tors.

How could I resolve this?
What happens if link time optimization removes the c-tors because it cannot know they're needed by plugins?

### Linking issue

When compiling and linking the plugin, the `Base:Base()` class' c-tor as well as the `Base::doSomething()` come out as unresolved symbol. The c-tor is called by the `Special::Special()` c-tor and cannot be resolved, of course. The other one is a virtual method

When compiling the application itself, it contains the implementations of the base class' methods. Obviously, they are not linked together when the plugin is loaded.

### SSCCE

```
/********** Interface.h */

#ifndef INTERFACE_H
#define INTERFACE_H
#include <QtPlugin>
#include "Base.h"

class Interface {
    public:
        virtual ~Interface() { }
        virtual Base *createWorker() = 0;
};


#define Interface_iid "blag"
Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(Interface, Interface_iid)
#endif

/********** App.pro */
QT += core

TARGET = App
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += \
  Base.cpp \
  App.cpp

HEADERS += \
  Base.h \
  Interface.h \

/********** Base.h */
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H
#include <QObject>

class Base:
    public QObject {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Base();
        virtual ~Base();
        virtual void doSomething();
};
#endif

/********** Base.cpp */

#include "Base.h"

Base::Base():
    QObject() {

}

Base::~Base() { }
void Base::doSomething() { }

/********** App.cpp */

#include "Interface.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QPluginLoader>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPluginLoader l("libPlugin.so");
    qDebug() << l.load();
    qDebug() << l.errorString();

    return a.exec();
}

/********** Plugin.pro */
TARGET = Plugin
CONFIG += plugin
TEMPLATE = lib
SOURCES += \
  Plugin.cpp \
  Special.cpp \

HEADERS += \
  Plugin.h \
  Special.h \
  Interface.h \
  Base.h

/********** Special.h */

#ifndef SPECIAL_H
#define SPECIAL_H
#include <QObject>
#include "Base.h"

class Special:
    public Base {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Special();
        void doSomething();
};
#endif

/********** Special.cpp */
#include "Special.h"

Special::Special():
    Base() {

}

void Special::doSomething() { }

/********** Plugin.h */
#ifndef PLUGIN_H
#define PLUGIN_H
#include <QObject>
#include "Interface.h"

class Q_DECL_EXPORT Plugin:
    public QObject,
    public Interface {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID Interface_iid)
        Q_INTERFACES(Interface)
    public:
        Base *createWorker();
};
#endif

/********** Plugin.cpp */
#include "Plugin.h"
#include "Special.h"

Base *Plugin::createWorker() {
    return new Special();
}
```

Build:

```
# Separate files
qmake Plugin.pro && make
qmake App.pro && make
./App
```

Comment: `Base() { /* Implementation */ }` -> That looks wrong. It should be Special, not Base. Also, just in case: `c++filt _ZN4BaseC2Ev
Base::Base()`. It is a weird thing to drop the parenting.

Comment: That was wrong indeed, corrected it. Also, the -C flag to nm does demangling as well :-)

Comment: Could you please paste the whole project as is without truncating it? Also, mention the Qt version, compiler, compiler version, OS, architecture, etc. As a side note, I am also surprised that you do not utilize C++11 more.

Comment: Of course. (Meta: is that okay to paste the whole bunch of [short] files right here in the question?) In what way would C++11 help here?

Comment: Yes, please paste everything that is relevant. It is called [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what is wrong.
The construction I'd like to have linked is as follows:

- A host application providing a base class with implementations
- A plugin shared library that inherits from that base and re-implements some methods and/or accesses the base class' members

This basically boils down to the following in plain C:

- A host application, providing some symbols
- A plugin shared library, providing some more symbols and wanting to use some of the host's symbols

However, there is no generic way to achieve the latter.
A host can *link against* a library to use its functionality. That means the host gets method stubs that are dynamically resolved into against library once the host itself and the library are loaded. Contract between library and host may be some header file with declarations (not definitions).

When a library is dynamically loaded into a host's memory, symbols in the library in turn are *not* resolved against the host, though. Instead they stay unresolved.

This is exactly what I am seeing here. I tried to resolve the base class' functionality (that I did not implement in the plugin) against the host application that wants to load the plugin. Does-not-work.

This is that `-rdynamic` is for on ELF, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706592/can-i-access-to-symbols-of-the-host-proccess-from-a-shared-object-loaded-in-runt).

Comment: Is this an answer or more like extension to your question? If it is the latter, please merge it into your question.

Comment: I actually think this answer is the answer to the problem. The problem cannot be resolved the way I tried, for the mentioned reason: No 'backward' linkage.

Comment: I'm still open for suggestions :-)

Comment: What about putting `Base` in a library of its own, which then each plugin would link against?